# Display single node from JSON in Angular > 10

Tags: json, angular

I would like to know how to display a single node from a json file in an angular application.

This is my data.json:

```
{
    "name": "John";
    "surname": "Doe
}
```

I would like to output into an angular component the result of the surname. So i can create a ReadJson component:

```
export class ReadJsonComponent implements OnInit {
data: any = (data as any).default;
  constructor() {
    console.log(data.surname);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

I am not able to do it on another component (eg a header). Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First import the JSON file like this.

```
import myJson = require("./myJson.json");
```

then set it in local variable,

```
 data: any = myJson;
```

then use it wherever you want.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  data: any = myJson;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("surname", this.data.surname);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Following your code, let's say that I put that in the AppComponent.
Now, how can I access `{{ data.surname }}` into a HeaderComponent, for example?

Comment: import again in header.compoenent.ts, better give me you scenario in stackbiltz, will able to help .

Comment: Thanks, so you mean that I have to import that in every component? There is no way to pass the json from parent to child? Thanks in advance

Comment: it is possible, to send data from parent to child in 2 ways, either use Services or @Input in child component.